# Control gulp-angular-filesort js order

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I'm using gulp to build app and gulp-angular-filesort to inject scripts into index.html file.

project structure is like the following:

```
app
  |_modules
          |_module1
                   |_module1.module.js
                   |_module1.controllers.js 
          |_module2
                   |_module2.module.js
                   |_module2.controllers.js 
          |_modules.module.js
```

let's say module1 uses module2. so, I would like module2 scripts were injected to before module1.

modules.module.js content:

> agnular.module('app.modules', ['app.modules.module2', 'app.modules.module1'])

modules.module1.js content:

> agnular.module('app.modules.module1', ['app.modules.module2'])

modules.module2.js content:

> agnular.module('app.modules.module2', [])

but anyway scripts are injected in wrong order: module1 are first then modul2. how can I control scripts order on right way?

Comment: How does your gulp task for injecting the files look like? The read option set to false can cause the problem, if you are using it? You also have a typo in the code above: "agnular" should be "angular"

Answer (score -2):

Although the basic usage of gulp-angular-filesort is obvious, I'll post it here along with some deviations I use.

```
var angularFilesort = require('gulp-angular-filesort'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject');

gulp.src('./src/app/index.html')
    .pipe(inject(
        gulp.src(['./src/app/**/*.js']).pipe(angularFilesort())
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
```

**"NOTE Do not use the read option for gulp.src! This plugin analyzes the contents of each file to determine sort order."**

This is directly taken from https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-filesort

The following example uses streams. I collect different js streams (e.g. from bower components, my own angular files and so on) and sort the angular files.

```
streams.applicationJS = function () {
    return gulp.src( src + "/js/**/*.js", {base: src} );
};

...

var libsAndAppJs = series( 
    streams.bowerFiles(), 
    streams.applicationJS().pipe( angularFilesort() ) 
);

var allIndex = gulp
    .src( src + "/htdocs/*/index.html", {base: src + "/htdocs"} )
    .pipe( inject( libsAndAppJs,
        {
            ignorePath: srcPrefix, addPrefix: "/directory"
        } ) );
```

And a slightly different example:

```
var jsFiles = gulp.src( "**/*.js", { "cwd": src + "/js" } )
    .pipe( rename( function ( path ) {
        path.dirname = "/dir/js/" + path.dirname;
    } ) )
    .pipe( angularFilesort() );

...

return gulp.src( indexFile )
    .pipe( inject( series( vendorJsFiles, jsFiles, vendorCssFiles, cssFiles ),
        {
            ignorePath: "bower_components",
            addSuffix: "?" + new Date().getTime()
        } ) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( dest ) )
    .on( "error", function ( err ) {
        console.log( err.message );
    } );
```